# AWS S3 Download Pause Method Does Not Work Properly

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, download, awss3transfermanager

I am trying to implement implement pause and resume mechanism for Amazon S3 SDK.

I am using TransferManager to start download and to resume it like the given example in the [link](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/pausing-and-resuming-transfers-using-transfer-manager/)

There is a problem with `downloadInstance.pause()` method.

It does not pause the download like in the `uploadInstance.tryPause(true)`

I have attached `ProgressListener` to `downloadInstance` like following:

```
TransferProgress progress = myDownload.getProgress();
```

I have tried to pause progress like following:

```
PersistableDownload persistableDownload = myDownload.pause();
```

After this point I have checked `progress` instance and see the progress changed in debug. So I can say that it is not pausing download operation as intended.

To resume the download from the `persistableDownload` instance, I have tried the following:

```
Download resumedDownload = transferManager.resumeDownload(persistableDownload);
```

I have also attached different `TransferProgress` instance to `resumeDownload` instance and I have seen that it is starting from beginning instead of resuming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the root cause of the problem. S3 is allowing parallel downloads as default and it is not possible to resume download if it is parallel downloaded as parts.